# Ruby | binread : failed to allocate memory (NoMemoryError)

Tags: ruby, memory

Running the following code

```
    Dir.foreach(FileUtils.pwd()) do |f|
        if f.end_with?('log')
            File.open(f) do |file|
                if File.size(f) > MAX_FILE_SIZE
                    puts f
                    puts file.ctime
                    puts file.mtime

                    # zipping the file
                    orig = f
                    Zlib::GzipWriter.open('arch_log.gz') do |gz|
                      gz.mtime = File.mtime(orig)
                      gz.orig_name = orig
                      gz.write IO.binread(orig)
                      puts "File has been archived"
                    end

                    #deleting the file
                    begin
                      File.delete(f)
                      puts "File has been deleted"
                    rescue Exception => e
                      puts "File #{f} can not be deleted"
                      puts "       Error #{e.message}"                
                      puts "======= Please remove file manually =========="
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
```

Also files are pretty heavy more than 1GB. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If the files you are reading are > 1GB, you have to have that much memory free at a minimum, because `IO.binread` is going to slurp that amount in.

You'd be better off to load a known amount and loop over the input until it's completely read, reading and writing in chunks.

From the docs:

```
  IO.binread(name, [length [, offset]] )   -> string

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Opens the file, optionally seeks to the given offset, then returns
length bytes (defaulting to the rest of the file). binread ensures
the file is closed before returning. The open mode would be "rb:ASCII-8BIT".

       IO.binread("testfile")           #=> "This is line one\nThis is line two\nThis is line three\nAnd so on...\n"
       IO.binread("testfile", 20)       #=> "This is line one\nThi"
       IO.binread("testfile", 20, 10)   #=> "ne one\nThis is line "
```

Comment: I too saw this in the docs, and I was wondering if there was an alternative more similar to file streams on .net, so ruby doesn't constantly create file handles on every call of binread.